# What is the 3D representation of a self-contained disc?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, 3d, transformational-geometry

Related: [If a rectangular grid, where left<->right and top<->bottom wrap, can be mapped onto the surface of a torus, what does a cube map to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66789/142244)

If there is a disc where a vector that crosses its edge re-enters the same disc on the opposite side, what is the 3D representation of this disc?

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a circle where a vector that crosses its edge re-enters the circle on the opposite side, what is the 3D representation of this circle?

I assume that by "circle" you mean a *circular [disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics))*. In mathematics, the word "circle" refers to the "outer rim" only; if you want to talk about the "inside" of a circle, you need to call it a disc.

If you take a circular disc and glue together opposite points on its edge, the resulting surface is called the [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane). There doesn't seem to be a "standard" or "usual" way of representing the real projective plane in 3 dimensions, and there is no representation of it which doesn't intersect itself.

That said, the Wikipedia article "[Real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane)" has pictures and descriptions of various "immersions" of the real projective plane in 3 dimensions.

Comment: my bad, language barrier. I'll fix the question.